# Read UDP data from a single remote endpoint without data loss

Tags: c++, udp, boost-asio

This is how I receive UDP datagrams (shortened, works great):

```
namespace ba = boost::asio;

ba::io_service _ioService;
ba::ip::udp::socket _socket(_ioService)

ba::ip::udp::endpoint senderEndpoint;

_socket.async_receive_from(ba::buffer(receiveBuffer, receiveBuffer.size()), 
    senderEndpoint, &handleReceive);
```

Is there a way to limit my `async_receive_from` to receive data from only one remote IP address *without consuming the data*?

There is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8488443/913577) that reads the data and throws it away if from wrong remote endpoint. I want to avoid reading it in the first place.

Background: I got multiple client devices with different IP addresses talking to my application (only one IP address). The applications is only interested in talking to one remote client at a time.

Comment: You can't peek using Boost ASIO. See e.g. [here for a workaround](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135904/boostasio-peeking-into-a-socket-buffer). Another workaround is to receive all packets, and put them (with peer information) in a container, and only "fetch" the wanted packets from that container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just issue a `connect()` to that IP address. Don't ask me how to do it in boost::asio, but it's possible at the BSD sockets level. It causes all datagrams from other IP addresses to be discarded, and also lets you use `send()` instead of `sendto()`. You can undo it by connecting to INADDR_ANY, I think, anyway it's documented.

Comment: There is a connect and an open function for udp sockets in asio. Gonna try connect...

Comment: Since UDP is a connectionless protocol, I wonder what connect actually does?

Comment: @RonaldMcBean No need to wonder. It does what I have stated in this answer. See *man connect(2)* for more information. if you're wondering *how,* it conditions the local API.